# Cobordism theory textbook

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am looking for a nice textbook on Cobordism/Bordism theory, which would include computation of main Corbordism rings(O- and U-cobordism at least) with detailed proofs. I found "Torsion in SU-bordism" written by Conner and Floyd which covers some material but still does not suit all my needs.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: "Notes on Cobordism Theory" by Robert Stong is the classic. Haynes Miller also has a collection of lecture notes called "Notes on Cobordism Theory", which is more modern and also well written.